# OpenWRT with NetBeans 7.3.1

Tags: c, netbeans, openwrt

I am an enthusiastic C/C++ programmer who is new to this firmware customization field of study. For my final year project, I am developing a solution to enhance the packet switching of a router and selected OpenWRT as my open-source firmware. I have been struggling a bit to set up the environment and would like to get your expert opinion on if I am on the correct path.

I followed the following steps to get openWRT to my local PC. (http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/buildroot.exigence).

In the make menuconfig, I have selected, - Advanced configuration Options -Automatic rebuild of packages -ToolChain Options -Build gdb -Build the OpenWRT Image Builder -Build the OpenWRT SDK -Build the OpenWRT based ToolChain

and saved the config and ran the commands, - make tools/install - make toolchain/install

Then in Netbeans, I added a new tool collection from Tools -> Options -> C/C++

and gave the base directory as '/openwrt/openwrt/toolchain'

and the C Complier as '/usr/bin/gcc'

Can you experts please advise me if I have done anything wrong? Is this sufficient to develop and compile a new C class to the openWRT firmware so that I can rebuild an image to be flashed into a router?

Your advice is much appreciated dear experts. I was struggling with this issue for quite some time :)

Thanks again :)

**EDIT**

The issue is that when i set the folder

`/openwrt/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.5-linaro_uClibc-0.9.32/i486-openwrt-linux`

which refers in the tutorial http://downloads.openwrt.org/docs/eclipse.pdf to be set as the cross compiler in the IDE it given an error stating that no Compiler is found in both the eclipse and Netbeans.

But it works when I point to the `/openwrt/openwrt/toolchain` directory.

My query is that is it okay to press on with the development and use the Compiler within the toolchain folder to compile the project?

**EDIT 2**

The output I get when I run the command

`find ./staging_dir -path "./staging_dir/toolchain*" -name *openwrt-linux`

within the openwrt folder as suggested by `TheCodeArtist` is

`./staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/mips-openwrt-l‌​inux`

**EDIT 3**

[image: Specifying the C compiler]

**EDIT 4**

[image: refined path]

Comment: A question that is open for 2 days, but that has a bounty? It seems that this is far too broad. Try to nail your problem down to a specific problem that seeks and answer and not "advice".

Comment: The main problem with your question is you do not say what happens when you do the above, and what you think is wrong. FWIW I would suggest building at the command line before you trying getting it to work in Netbeans.

Comment: @JensGustedt This question relates to my final year project of my degree..so, that is the reason why I was not hesitant to open up a bounty for this question :)

Comment: @Hasitha Just a sidebar. Are you trying to add "stuff" to the OpenWRT Linux-kernel or the filesystem? i.e. where does your additional C code go? A device driver in the linux kernel or a library/executable that runs in the userspace on a router running openwrt?...

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Hi, thank you for your reply. I want to add my own features to the firmware. which includes modifying the iptable and adding a few security features for packets before transmission. to answer your question "i think" it goes as a library executable :)

Comment: @Hasitha Also update your question with the details of the output of the following command within the openwrt directory `find ./staging_dir -path "./staging_dir/toolchain*" -name
*openwrt-linux`

Comment: @TheCodeArtist will do rytwaway :)

Comment: @TheCodeArtist the output I get is `./staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/mips-openwrt-linux
`

Comment: Based on the output of the `find` command, it appears that you have built ONLY the MIPS toolchain and NOT the x86 toolchain in openwrt. Now if you are trying to compile a x86-executable/library for x86 target then you do NOT have the toolchain setup properly yet. go back and check openwrt documentation as to how to build a x86 toolchain first. Alternately if you intend to build a MIPS-executable/library for a MIPS router, then use the directory returned by the find command as the cross-compiler directory in eclipse/netbeans. Ensure that you provide a proper "prefix" alongwith it.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Thank you very much for your information :) thanks alot :) really grateful and will post back the results as soon as am done with it :)

Comment: The **prefix** is usually the preceding string in the names of the binaries in the toolchain directory. For example if the names of the files are `arm-none-linux-gcc` arm-none-linux-ar` etc. then the prefix is `arm-none-linux-`. Since you seem to be having a MIPS toolchain, it would be something along the lines of `mips-*-gcc` etc. within the `./staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/mips-openwrt-l‌​inux` directory. Find and use the right prefix while specifying the toolchain directory.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Thanks alot for the help Sir! very much appreciate your contribution. :)

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Sir, i've attached a screenshot after specifying the C compiler. does that look ok?

Comment: I am not quite sure you got it right. The usual convention is to provide the toolchain directory `./staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/initial/bin` as the `base directory`. Next provide relative paths/filenames of gcc, g++ etc. in the individual fileds for `C compiler` ad `C++ compiler` etc. i.e. `mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc` and `mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc-g++` respectively. The idea is that when the IDE needs to run the C/C++ compiler, it can locate them by concatenating the BaseDir + compilerName and use the resulting full-path to run the compilation command.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist I did what you mentioned and when I specified `./staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/initial/bin` as base directory it says that `No Compiler sets were found in the directory`. I have to manually specify the tool collection family. But it works for the `openwrt/toolchain` folder as it picks up the tool collection family up as `GNU`. id it ok if i specify the tool collection family as GNU manually ? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the **appropriate toolchain directory** for the target architecture (x86, arm, mips etc.) based on the device you intend to run the resulting executables as the **`Base Directory`**.

Next provide the **relative path/filenames of the individual commands** for **`C compiler`**, **`C++ compiler`** etc. These will be relative paths(including the filenames) to the appropriate binaries within the toolchain directory specified above.

---

#### How to verify the toolchain settings?

Using the IDE, compile a simple `hello-world.c` program. Something like

```
/* hello-world.c */
int main()
{
    return (42);
}
```

Give a **`Build`** using the IDE and check the compilation output window. Understand the errors if any and modify the configuration options accordingly.

Once a build succeeds and it will result in a binary `hello-world` within the project directory. Open a new terminal and run the **`file`** command on newly generated binary to verify that it is indeed built for the target architecture. For example a binary built for x86-64 would show.

```
$ file hello-world
hello-world: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
```

In your case i assume it would be a `MIPS` executable if the mips toolchain and compiler are properly configured within the IDE settings.

Comment: Thank you for this descriptive answer sir! I will try this out and post back :) thanks again :)

Comment: Sir, the output i got was this `main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xad0d0ababd4debc5d04bd19e0277d2d862344bbc, not stripped` does this mean its successfully configured? and I've attached the new configurations as Edit 4.. the make and debugger commands can be default right? or do they have to be changed? Thank you :)

Comment: This looks good if you were trying to compile for x86-64. However, this should NOT have been the case though since the screenshot you shared shows a MIPS toolchain directory. There are a lot of things that could have possibly gone wrong. I would suggest you to familiarise yourself with the concept of cross-compilation and follow a simple tutorial like **[this](http://giovanni.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/how-to-cross-compile-a-c-program-for-openwrt/)** to get you started. this would help you undersatnmd where you are going wrong when setting-up the toolchain for the IDE.

Comment: Thanks alot sir..i will check on this :)

Comment: The link you referred is awesome sir..got it working.. and seems il have to just use the IDE to keep the syntaxes correct and use the terminal to compile manually. nevertheless its very helpful and finally i can proceed with the development. Thanks again :)